# Could not determine jupyterlab build status without nodejs

Tags: node.js, jupyter-lab

I'm seeing this error in the terminal: "Could not determine jupyterlab build status without nodejs". Even when latest version of nodejs is installed on my PC.

Please guide what should I do?

Answer (score 12):

I ran into a similar issue this morning and ended up here.  The diagnostic message appears to be harmless:

```
[W 07:35:51.998 LabApp] Could not determine jupyterlab build status without nodejs
```

However, the way I resolved it for my configuration (Windows 10, Anaconda distribution of Python 3.7) was to [download NodeJS from the source](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).  Choose the LTS (Long Term Support) version of Node.js rather than the "Current with the latest features" edition.

Next, ensure the node executable is in the search path.  On Windows, hold the Windows key and Break.  Click on Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables -> System Variables.  Double click PATH to edit.  Click OK until you're out.

In a new command window, run:

```
jupyter lab
```

You're looking for something like this in the output:

```
[I 07:16:26.721 LabApp] Node v10.15.3
```

Comment: best answer for sure, thanks for the full explanation and fix

Comment: Any idea how to ensure it picks up in a new environment. Since path returns node when no environment is activated, but when I try after activating an environment it doesn't return node path

Comment: @Eswar Chitirala: activate the environment and then run conda:
conda install -c conda-forge nodejs

Answer (score 11):

On Unbuntu 20.04, just activate the environment and install by conda:

> conda install -c conda-forge nodejs

Answer (score 3):

Try the command below, follow through the prompt and see if it helps in your issue.

```
jupyter lab --debug
```

You can check your installation of npm or nodes by using

```
node -v
npm -v
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I got the same error message, on Win10, and just restarted the virtual environment, restarted jupyter lab and have not had the error since (several days). Doesnt help of course if there is an underlying issue:)

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OS/Windows: install LTS version of Node.js from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and restart jupyter lab.

Answer (score 0):

I installed it from source but it looks like a version had installed on conda that was old, which was causing this issue. If you've installed nodejs with conda  (or something similar) you will get an outdated version, uninstall it and install it from the nodejs website manually. The error will fix.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, on Linux Mint LMDE 5, installing with pip solved the problem:

pip install nodejs

Answer (score 0):

I've just installed nodejs (in an environment other than base), but that message still persists. (Windows 11)

pip install nodejs

(I check with conda list nodejs, pip and conda know either other's installation)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

still need python binding for nodejs

```
sudo pip install nodejs
```

Comment: Is the `sudo` important? If so, please explain why. If not, then don't add duplicate answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72779246/